# Multiple unions

Tags: r

I am trying to do unions on several lists (these are actually GRanges objects not integer lists but the priciple is the same), basically one big union.

```
x<-sort(sample(1:20, 9))
y<-sort(sample(10:30, 9))
z<-sort(sample(20:40, 9))
mylists<-c("x","y","z")
emptyList<-list()
sapply(mylists,FUN=function(x){emptyList<-union(emptyList,get(x))})
```

That is just returning the list contents.
I need the equivalent of

```
union(x,union(y,z))
[1]  2  3  5  6  7 10 13 15 20 14 19 21 24 27 28 29 26 31 36 39
```

but written in an extensible and non-"variable explicit" form

Comment: seems like identifying the variables with a string, `mylists<-c("x","y","z")`, is generally unsafe. Why not `mylist<-c(x,y,z)`?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

A not necessarily memory efficient paradigm that will work with GRanges is

```
Reduce(union, list(x, y, z))
```

The argument might also be a `GRangesList(x, y, z)` for appropriate values of `x` etc.

Comment: i'v found this won't work on large lists.  Uses c instead of union.

Answer (score 8):

```
x<-sort(sample(1:20, 9))
y<-sort(sample(10:30, 9))
z<-sort(sample(20:40, 9))
```

Both of the below produce the same output

```
unique(c(x,y,z))
[1]  1  2  4  6  7  8 11 15 17 14 16 18 21 23 26 28 29 20 22 25 31 32 35

union(x,union(y,z))
[1]  1  2  4  6  7  8 11 15 17 14 16 18 21 23 26 28 29 20 22 25 31 32 35
```

Answer (score 3):

This can be done by using the reduce function in the purrr package.

`purrr::reduce(list(x, y, z),union)`

Answer (score 2):

```
unique(unlist(mget(mylists, globalenv())))
```

will do the trick.  (Possibly changing the environment given in the call to `mget`, as required.)

Comment: If you look at the code for `union`, you'll see that it just calls `unique` on a pair of vector inputs.

Answer (score 2):

I think it would be cleaner to separate the "dereference" part from the n-ary union part, e.g.

```
dereflist <- function(l) lapply(a,get)
nunion <- function(l) Reduce(union,l)
```

But if you look at how union works, you'll see that you could also do

```
nunion <- function(l) unique(do.call(c,l))
```

which is faster in all the cases I've tested (*much* faster for long lists).

-s

Comment: Can you provide a full example of how you would call each of your functions to affect a solution, given the original objects from the Q. Otherwise, what is the point?

Comment: Really?  I'd like to think the original poster can figure out that nunion(dereflist(...)) will do it.

Comment: It was the nesting of `dereflist()` *inside* `nunion()` that wasn't clear when I wrote the comment.

Answer (score 1):

ok this works but I am curious why sapply seems to have its own scope

```
x<-sort(sample(1:20, 9))
y<-sort(sample(10:30, 9))
z<-sort(sample(20:40, 9))
mylists<-c("x","y","z")
emptyList<-vector()
for(f in mylists){emptyList<-union(emptyList,get(f))}
```

Comment: In the question, `function(x){emptyList<-union(emptyList,get(x))}` assigns a local variable called `emptyList`.  It does not overwrite the global value, which is why the code does not work.