# How to make union of n sets using R?

Tags: r, list, union

I have a list `g1` which consists of 1000 sublists. I want to make the union of all lists. I can make the manual entry like this-

```
union(g1[[1]],g1[[2]],g1[[3]]) and so on
```

But I want to automate the process using loops in R. I tried using this code-

```
for(i in 1:1000){g2<-union(g1[[i]])}
```

But this gives me final sublist, not the entire union. How it could be done?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You might find [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5516070/multiple-unions) helpful

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can use

```
Reduce(union, g1)
```

If you want to do only with for loop:

```
g2 = g1[[1]]
for(i in 2:1000){
    g2<-union(g2, g1[[i]])
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with

```
unique( unlist(g1) )
```

This would give an array as output anyway